# I am getting a problem while understanding the UserMixin in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am currently learning flask and I have heard about the concept called UserMixin can anybody please tell what does it mean and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserMixin` is part of [`flask-login`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/) package that implements user authentication functionality. In order for `flask-login` to work, it expects your `User` object to have certain pre-defined methods, like `get_id()`, `is_authenticated()`, etc (you can see what these are [in the docs here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/mixins.html#UserMixin)). Technically you don't have to use the mixin and implement these methods yourself, but extending from mixin is a nice shortcut.